# ValueError trying to remove elements from a pandas dataframe that are in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove items from a pandas dataframe that have a value for column a that is part of a list.

```
import pandas as pd

a = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz']
b = [1,2,3,2,1,1,3,2,1]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(a, b), columns = ['a', 'b'])
print(df)
verwijder = ['jkl', 'mno', 'vwx']
df = df[df['a'] not in verwijder]
print(df)
```

The above throws an `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html). `not in` doesn't support operation on Series.

```py
df = df[~df['a'].isin(verwijder)]
```